# Image Overlay Effect On click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an on click image overlay, where you click the left icon and an image fades or slides in, but when you click the right icon a different image fades or slides in. Also, when you click either icon, the associated images fade or slide out.

I've been trying to use

```
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

to make the display go from none to block when you click the icon, but there is no way to use this function with two separate links. I am not very great with javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/hzfw00L7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? I have used Jquery to speed up the coding!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".left").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").fadeIn(3000);
  });
  $(".right").click(function() {
    $("#overlay2").fadeIn(3000);
  });
  $("#overlay").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(2000);
  });
  $("#overlay2").click(function() {
    $("#overlay2").fadeOut(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#content {
  padding: 20px;
}

a.left {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
}

a.right {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  right: 80px;
  z-index: 7;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: magenta;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
}

#buttons {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="text">Overlay Text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay2">
    <div id="text">Overlay Text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="buttons">
      <a class="left">Turn on overlay effect</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <a class="right">Turn on overlay effect 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Added Fade in and fade out animations!
[For More Reference Go here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

Comment: Yes! That's perfect, thank you so much. Do you also know of any simple ways to make the overlays fade or slide in?

https://jsfiddle.net/hzfw00L7/2/

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer helped you then please upvote and select it as answer!

Comment: I have updated the code to fade in and out! Please check the updated answer! and also please make sure to refer the link!

Comment: Thank you yes! Whenever I click one of the boxes it gives me an error message though, how do I get rid of that?

Comment: Error Message ? Did you tried this in your JSFiddle? What is the Error Message?

Comment: Oh never mind, I think it was just my browser. I was getting the error in Chrome but not other browsers for some reason. It works great, thank you so much!